# Actionscript 3 mouseover issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Hi I'm a total novice with actionscript so any help is greatly appreciated.

Basically I have a movie with 2 layers, 1 has closed eyes on the other open eyes.

So the functionality should be that the movie starts with they eyes closed the when the mouse rolls over the movie the eyes open and then when the mouse leaves the movie they close again.

This is the code I have at present, but it isn't working:

```
package 
{

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

eyes_closed.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, hideEyes);
eyes_closed.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, openEyes);

function hideEyes(event:MouseEvent):void {
  eyes_open.visible = true;
}

function openEyes(event:MouseEvent):void {
  eyes_closed.visible = true;
}

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: At least you don't listen for `MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT` event to "close" the eyes. Also, you should better use a container for both `eyes_closed` and `eyes_open` that'll contain either one or another, and attach listeners to that container.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options to do what you are trying, one simple solution is :

create 2 layers of sprites - one with eyes closed and over it one with eyes opened (probably you've done it already)

add 2 event listeners to the bottom sprite (eyes_closed)  - mouse over ->show eyes_open , mouse_out -> hide eyes_open

Now this is important - on your eyes_open sprite (the top one of the 2) add

```
eyes_open.mouseEnabled = false
eyes_open.mouseChildren = false
```

Comment: something else worth mentioning might be that the movie clip plays the eyes blinking intemitently, would this effect it?

Comment: is it playing it when you hover over the eyes or all the time ?

Comment: it's playing all the time.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution (no pun intended) is to use the [SimpleButton](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/SimpleButton.html) class. It lets you create one display object which internally displays different display objects depending on 3 states (normal, mouse over, and mouse down). Also, a 4:th display object determines the "hit area" (usually the same as the display object used for the normal state).

Example:

```
import flash.display.SimpleButton;

var closed : MovieClip = new closedMC();
var open : MovieClip = new openMC();

var button : SimpleButton = new SimpleButton(closed, open, open, closed);
```

One thing though: If you use MovieClip with animation, the MovieClip will restart from frame 1 when the state changes (when you press the button for instance).

Answer (score 0):

You want to make one invisible when you make the other visible.

```
package 
{



    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    eyes_closed.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, hideEyes);
    eyes_closed.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, openEyes);

    function hideEyes(event:MouseEvent):void {
      eyes_open.visible = true;
      eyes_closed.visible = false;
    }

    function openEyes(event:MouseEvent):void {
      eyes_closed.visible = true;
      eyes_open.visible = false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to hide the eyes.

```
function hideEyes(event:MouseEvent):void {
  eyes_open.visible = true;
  eyes_closed.visible = false;
}

function openEyes(event:MouseEvent):void {
  eyes_closed.visible = true;
  eyes_open.visible = false;
}
```

Another option: change layer order using `setChildIndex`